# Add one day to custom date in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I need to add one extra day to the specific day ,kindly help me

let say I want to add one day to this date "31/12/2020"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ7Hr.png)

Comment: Perhaps this will help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608462/freemarker-velocity-date-manipulation

Comment: hi @soorapadman, thanks for reply,getting formatting error while saving

Comment: am trying something like below <#assign dateToday = renewalDate />
    
 <#assign extraday = dateToday + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) />
 <#assign neewdate=extraday?number_to_datetime> but its throwing the error

Comment: @user2703469 You need to convert the date to number via `?long` first if you want to do math like that. However, I would be very careful, as you aren't dealing with time instants here, but with something that looks like a local date. Therefore, daylight saving time changes can bite you. So move to noon from midnight.